# Замыкания и присвоение переменной в js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, замыкания

Хочу с помощью следующего цикла, разместить в таблице несколько `<td>`. Однако, каждому `<td>`, надо задать свойства *onmouseenter* и *onmouseleave*.

```
function getItems(){
    var len = stickers.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        tbl = document.getElementById("itemsTable");
        if(i==0||(i>4&&WIDTH>650)||i>2){
            row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        }else{
            row = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            row = row[row.length-1];
        }
        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.className = "items";
        cell.id = "item"+(i+1);
        c = document.getElementById("item"+(i+1));
        c.style.backgroundImage = "url("+stickers[i][1]+")";
        c.style.opacity = 0.0;
        //itemId = "item"+(i+1);
        //itemName = itemId+"description";
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {outOfShadow("item"+(i+1), 1)};
        img.src = stickers[i][1];
        c.onmouseenter = function(){outOfShadow("item"+(i+1)+"description", 1)};
        c.onmouseleave = function(){intoShadow("item"+(i+1)+"description", 0)};
    }
}
```

Собственно, ничего не работает.. Не понимаю почему(
Если раскомментировать строчки и заменить ими `"item"+(i+1)` и `"item"+(i+1)+"description"`, получается уже половина рабочего кода, но присваивается всем объектам i+1 равное длине массива stickers.
Можно пожалуйста получить отредактированный код, который работает верно?
Я не совсем понимаю, где именно должны находиться замыкания.

Comment: почитайте про замыкания: https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в js каждый вызов функции создает неявный объект `scope`  который ссылается на переменные вне функции а также содержит в себе локальные переменные этой функции. А не работает потому что обработчики событий на mouseenter и mouseleave получают значение `i` из одного и того же scope в котором к концу выполнения цикла значение переменной `i` становится равным `len`.

Вам необходимо чтобы каждый обработчик ссылался на свой `i`-ый scope. 
то есть так:

```
function getItems() {
    var len = stickers.length;          
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {      
        c.onmouseenter = function(x) {
            return function() {
                outOfShadow("item"+(x)+"description", 1);
            }
        }(i+1); // i ый scope ссылается на текущее значение i в цикле.

        c.onmouseleave = function(x) {
            return function() {
                intoShadow("item"+(x)+"description", 0);
            };
        }(i+1); //  тоже самое и здесь
    }
}
```

Comment: больше спасибо, теперь я разобрался!